# Python unicode error dependent on the path I supply?

Tags: python, ubuntu, python-2.7

I have been having some issues executing a command (launching IPython) over SSH. In troubleshooting it, I've come across something I can't understand. IPython either launches or doesn't dependent on whether I supply the full path or not - what's going wrong here?

`/home/ubuntu/anaconda/bin/ipython notebook —-profile=server`

...gives me the errors below, while:

`~/anaconda/bin/ipython notebook --profile=server`

...loads IPython flawlessly.

It's worth confirming that when I go to my home directory by typing cd, I do indeed get /home/ubuntu

Full stack trace:

> ubuntu@ip-10-204-37-226:~$ /home/ubuntu/anaconda/bin/ipython notebook
>   —-profile=server Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/home/ubuntu/anaconda/bin/ipython", line 6, in 
>       sys.exit(start_ipython())   File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/**init**.py",
>   line 118, in start_ipython
>       return launch_new_instance(argv=argv, **kwargs)   File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/config/application.py",
>   line 544, in launch_instance
>       app.initialize(argv)   File "", line 2, in initialize   File
>   "/home/ubuntu/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/config/application.py",
>   line 89, in catch_config_error
>       return method(app, *args, **kwargs)   File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/terminal/ipapp.py",
>   line 312, in initialize
>       super(TerminalIPythonApp, self).initialize(argv)   File "", line 2, in initialize   File
>   "/home/ubuntu/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/config/application.py",
>   line 89, in catch_config_error
>       return method(app, *args, **kwargs)   File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/application.py",
>   line 362, in initialize
>       self.parse_command_line(argv)   File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/terminal/ipapp.py",
>   line 307, in parse_command_line
>       return super(TerminalIPythonApp, self).parse_command_line(argv)   File "", line 2, in parse_command_line   File
>   "/home/ubuntu/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/config/application.py",
>   line 89, in catch_config_error
>       return method(app, *args, **kwargs)   File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/config/application.py",
>   line 463, in parse_command_line
>       self.argv = list(argv)   File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/utils/traitlets.py",
>   line 315, in **set**
>       new_value = self._validate(obj, value)   File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/utils/traitlets.py",
>   line 323, in _validate
>       return self.validate(obj, value)   File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/utils/traitlets.py",
>   line 1215, in validate
>       value = self.validate_elements(obj, value)   File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/utils/traitlets.py",
>   line 1291, in validate_elements
>       return super(List, self).validate_elements(obj, value)   File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/utils/traitlets.py",
>   line 1225, in validate_elements
>       v = self._trait.validate(obj, v)   File "/home/ubuntu/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/utils/traitlets.py",
>   line 1028, in validate
>       return unicode(value) UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe2 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: Is that a misspell in `—-profile=server`?

Comment: No, the profile is `server`, not `nbserver` as is more common. And one works and the other doesn't so it must be something different between them.

Comment: No, @SAM means `—-` vs `--`. Really hard to see.

Comment: Yes!! That's it. Thanks. Can't believe I had been struggling for so long for so few pixels. Thanks guys.